# Don't linear combinations of partial derivatives entirely determine Jacobian?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm learning multivariable calculus for the first time, having just taken a course on theoretical linear algebra and group theory, and the instructor motivated the Jacobian definition of a function derivative by giving an example of how, if we defined a multivariable derivative purely in terms of the existence of partial derivatives, we could get functions that are not continuous at a point, but for which the derivative still exists, which violates what we want from a definition of a derivative (as a stronger condition than continuity), and so we instead take the "existence of a linear map" definition instead.

But doesn't the existence of enough partial derivatives completely determine the Jacobian? For example, if you had $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ for all components $0 \le i \le n$ for $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, don't you automatically guarantee the existence of the Jacobian
$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \cdots \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$$ by just using the partial derivatives you've shown exist. And does the existence of such a Jacobian satisfy the "existence of a linear map" condition to show that $f$ is differentiable, as a multivariable function?

My intuition is breaking down because I intuitively imagine a function as differentiable if the limits from all possible paths exist, and are the same. Aren't said limits entirely specified by these set of partial derivatives, from which you can get any direction derivative by a linear combination? And so in some sense, you've specified the datum for the "total derivative" (ie. $Df(x)$) when specifying *all* the partial derivatives?

Comment: Hi, I think that the problem is that these partial derivatives need to be continuous. If derivation exists then your intuition is correct - if you approximate the function at the point by some linear function, then indeed, in any direction you can calculate derivation in this direction as a linear combination of partial derivatives. But general multivariable function can be quite wild and there is a continuum of possible paths, so there is apriori no reason why they should be determined by partial derivatives (which is just finitely many paths).

Comment: @dmk Do you mean that if the partial derivatives are themselves continuous, the existence of all of them does imply the original function is differentiable? I don't quite understand what you mean in your last sentence.

Comment: There is a Theorem that if partial derivatives exist and are continuous then derivative of the original function exists. I don't recall details but I believe you should be able to find it online or in your textbook.  (I found some posts here on MSE commenting that converse is not true, that function  may have derivative but not continuous partial derivatives)

Comment: Perhaps you know those strange problems where we are given a rational function like $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2 + 2y^2},$$ identically zero on the two axes, but not continuous at $(0,0)$.  Of course for such a function both partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$ but it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existence of the Jacobian matrix at $c$ only needs, by definition, the partial derivatives at $c$. It is also true that a function is differentiable at $c$ if and only if the Jacobian exists at $c$ and $\lim_{\lvert h\rvert\to0}\frac{\left\lvert f(c+h)-f(c)-\nabla_c f\cdot h\right\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}=0$.

However, it might still not be the case that, while the Jacobian at $c$ exists, $$\lim_{\lvert h\rvert\to0}\frac{\left\lvert f(c+h)-f(c)-\nabla_c f\cdot h\right\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}=0$$

For instance, consider $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\le 0\lor y\le x^2\lor y\ge 4x^2\\ (x^2+y^2)^{1/4}\exp\left(\frac{1}{(y-x^2)(y-4x^2)}+\frac49x^{-4}\right)&\text{if }x>0\land x^2<y<4x^2\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}=0$ for all $v\in\Bbb R^2$, $f$ is continuous, but $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ because $$\limsup_{h\to 0}\frac{\lvert f(h)-f(0)-\nabla_0f\cdot h\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}\ge\limsup_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\lvert f(t,5t^2/2)\rvert}{\lvert (t,5t^2/2)\rvert}=\limsup_{t\to 0^+}\left(t^2+\frac{25}{4}t^4\right)^{-1/4}=\infty$$

Also, $(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}f(x,y)$ is again $C^\infty(\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\})$, has all the directional derivatives equal to $0$ at $0$ and it isn't continuous at $0$.

Of course, by the total differential theorem, existence of the partial derivatives in a neighbourhood of $c$ and continuity of the partial derivatives at $c$ is sufficient to guarantee differentiability at $c$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!